# Perl printing array of array of hashes?

Tags: perl, twitter, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I'm using Net::Twitter to access my twitter messages. Currently direct_message() returns an array of the messages. What I found out is it's really an array of arrays (based on the account then each individual message).

I wanted to know if anyone knows a better way to print the message id's from the results? I only figured it was an array of an array since $msgs[0][0]{'id'} would print out the message id. When I did data dumper it looked more like it was an array of hashes.

```
foreach my $msg (@{$msgs[0]})
{
    print $msg->{'id'} . "\n";
}
```

Data::Dumper Results

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'sender_screen_name' => 'text',
        'recipient' => {
                         'friends_count' => 'text',
                         'follow_request_sent' => 'text',
                         'profile_background_image_url_https' => 'text',
                         'profile_sidebar_fill_color' => 'text',
                         'profile_image_url' => 'text',
                         'profile_background_color' => 'text',
                         'notifications' => 'text',
                         'url' => 'text',
                         'id' => 'text',
                         'is_translator' => 'text',
                         'following' => 'text',
                         'screen_name' => 'text',
                         'lang' => 'text',
                         'location' => 'text',
                         'followers_count' => 'text',
                         'statuses_count' => 'text',
                         'name' => 'text',
                         'description' => 'text',
                         'favourites_count' => 'text',
                         'profile_background_tile' => 'text',
                         'listed_count' => 'text',
                         'contributors_enabled' => 'text',
                         'profile_link_color' => 'text',
                         'profile_image_url_https' => 'text',
                         'profile_sidebar_border_color' => 'text',
                         'created_at' => 'text',
                         'utc_offset' => 'text',
                         'verified' => 'text',
                         'show_all_inline_media' => 'text',
                         'profile_background_image_url' => 'text',
                         'protected' => 'text',
                         'default_profile' => 'text',
                         'id_str' => 'text',
                         'profile_text_color' => 'text',
                         'default_profile_image' => 'text',
                         'time_zone' => 'text',
                         'profile_use_background_image' => 'text',
                         'geo_enabled' => 'text',
                       },
        'id_str' => 'text',
        'sender_id' => 'text',
        'created_at' => 'text',
        'text' => 'text',
        'sender' => {
                      'friends_count' => 'text',
                      'follow_request_sent' => 'text',
                      'profile_background_image_url_https' => 'text',
                      'profile_sidebar_fill_color' => 'text',
                      'profile_image_url' => 'text',
                      'profile_background_color' => 'text',
                      'notifications' => 'text',
                      'url' => 'text',
                      'id' => 'text',
                      'is_translator' => 'text',
                      'following' => 'text',
                      'screen_name' => 'text',
                      'lang' => 'text',
                      'location' => 'text',
                      'followers_count' => 'text',
                      'statuses_count' => 'text',
                      'name' => 'text',
                      'description' => 'text',
                      'favourites_count' => 'text',
                      'profile_background_tile' => 'text',
                      'listed_count' => 'text',
                      'contributors_enabled' => 'text',
                      'profile_banner_url' => 'text',
                      'profile_link_color' => 'text',
                      'profile_image_url_https' => 'text',
                      'profile_sidebar_border_color' => 'text',
                      'created_at' => 'text',
                      'utc_offset' => 'text',
                      'verified' => 'text',
                      'show_all_inline_media' => 'text',
                      'profile_background_image_url' => 'text',
                      'protected' => 'text',
                      'default_profile' => 'text',
                      'id_str' => 'text',
                      'profile_text_color' => 'text',
                      'default_profile_image' => 'text',
                      'time_zone' => 'text',
                      'profile_use_background_image' => 'text',
                      'geo_enabled' => 'text',
                    },
        'recipient_screen_name' => 'text',
        'id' => 'text',
        'recipient_id' => 'text',
      }
    ];
```

Comment: Include the Data-Dumper output and perhaps the format of what you want to see.

Comment: @SethRobertson I've included the Data-Dumper output. I'm just wanting to access each messages ID ('id' key second from the bottom)  and the message (hash 'text' right above the sender hash). Doing a simple print $msgs[0][0]{'id'}, $msgs[0][1]{'id'} would give me the id of the first and second messages respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at `Net::Twitter` and it's very skeletal in nature. It refers you back to the API, and pretty much leaves you at that -- mainly because the APIs are constantly changing which makes it hard to produce a stable module. Most modules try to clean up the *reference to a reference to an array of hash references to a hash of arrays* mess, but this one doesn't.

It looks like you have to use `Data::Dumper` to see what data structure is being returned, and parse it the best way you can.

In situations like this, you can use the [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) command to verify exactly what you're looking at (if it returns a reference to a hash when you're expecting a reference to an array, you know you might be in trouble that way). You can also take a look at [`Net::Twitter::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aTwitter%3a%3aLite) which might provide a bit more support for basic object handling.

Comment: Yeah I did use Data::Dumper but it looked like an array of hashes. Which is why the extra [0] was throwing me off I didn't know if there might be a better way then what I figured out worked.